# DirectX 9 Triangle List drawing through itself, how do I set up a depth buffer?

Tags: c#, directx-9

I am having trouble breaking down a bug I am seeing in my DirectX 9 application. I am rendering a triangle list, with no culling (bug shows up either way), using a vertex buffer. When I look at the rendered triangle strip from a certain direction, the base of the strip (the farthest part away) will draw through parts that should be above it. It is a bit difficult to explain in words, so I will try to show what's happening through images.

[image: Expected drawing]

The above is what I expect to see, the tip of the cone is rendered above the black base. It works when looking in this direction.

[image: Why is the base drawing ontop of the cone!?]

And above is what I get when looking at it from the bad direction. Notice how the black base draws over the middle of the cone. This is horrible and not at all what I want to happen.

[image]

Interestingly, if you go to the other side and look in the bad direction, it is the cone that is drawn above the base when the base should be what's drawn (as seen above). This is NOT seen if back culling (CounterClockwise) is used. I hope this can give someone with more experience a bit of help in figuring out what's wrong.

Anyways, I don't even know where to begin with tracking this bug down as I am fairly new to DirectX. I figure there could be a number of reasons:

- The depth buffer is too imprecise
- I am not setting up depth buffering properly
- I am not defining my vertices in the proper order
- I am not drawing the vertex buffer correctly
- ...

In this application, there is no lighting setup, and the I am using `CustomVertex.PositionTextured` for the vertices. I am hoping someone can help me narrow down this problem, as I think (hope) it is a fairly simple one, but I have been stuck with it for hours now.

**EDIT**

My guess bet is that the depth buffer has not been initialized. In fact, I haven't done it. What I have for code for initializing of Device is:

```
 presentParameters.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Copy;

 device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Reference, this, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, presentParameters);
```

Naturally, that didn't set up the depth buffer. However it at least displays what I have shown. I've tried the following code in attempt to setup the depth buffer:

```
presentParameters.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Copy;
presentParameters.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
presentParameters.AutoDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.D16;

device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Reference, this, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, presentParameters);
device.RenderState.ZBufferEnable = true;
```

Now the model doesn't display at all. Here's how I am clearing and drawing the scene:

```
device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.SlateGray, 1.0f, 0);

SetupCamera();
SetupTransformations();

//Begin scene
device.BeginScene();

Draw();

device.EndScene();
device.Present();
```

What am I doing wrong when it comes to setting up the depth buffer?

**EDIT2**

<s>I have noticed that I have an error in device after it is created:</s>

```
+       RasterStatus    'device.RasterStatus' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.InvalidCallException'  Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.RasterStatus {Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.InvalidCallException}
```

This occurs for both. One thing I should mention is I am drawing this on a Form. I have another application I am looking at for help that draws it to a custom user control and it does not have this error. Anyways, I do not know how to decode this error and Google has been of no help.

That doesn't happen when I switch to `DeviceType.Hardware`. I am still using a Form though, would that be a problem?

Comment: My guess is depth buffering.  Do you have your z-buffer enabled?

Comment: Adding in `device.RenderState.ZBufferEnable = true;` doesn't change anything. So I guess it's enabled by default? Edit: This is what I am using for clearing the screen, `device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.SlateGray, 1.0f, 0);` Does that look alright?

Comment: So I think you're right @Matthew, I never set up a z-buffer of any kind...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I forgot to clear the zbuffer in the device.Clear call:

```
device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target | ClearFlags.ZBuffer, Color.SlateGray, 1.0f, 0);
```

and now it works!